# Calculate the Taylor-series for $f : x \mapsto \frac{1}{1+2x}$ and find its radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

> From an old exam:
>
> Calculate the Taylor-series for $f : x \mapsto \frac{1}{1+2x}$ at
>   $x_{0} = 0$ . What's the radius of convergence of it?

Alright, so it wasn't mentioned how many derivates we gonna need, I guess the more the better / clear it is. Here I have created the first 4 derivatives:

$$f^{(0)} = \frac{1}{1+2x}$$

$$f^{(1)}= -\frac{2}{\left ({1+2x}\right )^{2}}$$

$$f^{(2)}= \frac{8}{\left ({1+2x}\right )^{3}}$$

$$f^{(3)}= -\frac{48}{\left ({1+2x}\right )^{4}}$$

$$f^{(4)}= \frac{384}{\left ({1+2x}\right )^{5}}$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\left ( T_{4,0}f \right ) (x) = \frac{f^{(0)}(0)}{0!} \cdot \left (x-0 \right )^{0} + \frac{f^{(1)}(0)}{1!} \cdot \left (x-0 \right )^{1} + \frac{f^{(2)}(0)}{2!} \cdot \left (x-0 \right )^{2} + \frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!} \cdot \left (x-0 \right )^{3} + \frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!} \cdot \left (x-0 \right )^{4} + ...$$

$$= \frac{1}{1}\cdot 1 + \frac{-2}{1} \cdot x + \frac{8}{2} \cdot x^{2} + \frac{-48}{6} \cdot x^{3} + \frac{384}{24} \cdot x^{4} + ...$$

$$= 1-2x+4x^{2}-8x^{3}+16x^{4}-...$$

From this, I made the series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( -1 \right)^{n} \cdot 2^{n}\cdot x^{n}$$

I believe I did it right so far...?

And now the radius of convergence humm... For this we have always used the ratio test (ignore the $x^{n})$ and just do ratio test. In the end, take the reciprocal of the result and it will be your radius of convergence.

But how would you use ratio test on the series above..? It seems impossible.

Comment: You could have set $x=\frac y2$ and make a long division. The pattern would be quite clear even if you do not know the Taylor expansion of $\frac 1 {1+y}$. When done, replace $y$ by $2x$.

Comment: $$\biggl\lvert \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cdot 2^{n+1}}{(-1)^n\cdot 2^n}\biggr\rvert$$ doesn't look too frightening.

Comment: Oh then the ugly $(-1)^{n}$ gets eliminated, $(2)^{n}$ too... this looks so great, I think I got very big use for this let me try on paper, tyvm!

Comment: If I did correctly using your approach, the radius of convergence is $-\frac{1}{2}$. Is that right?

Comment: Not quite. The radius of convergence is always nonnegative. You forgot the modulus.

Comment: Oh right! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did above is correct. However, it doesn't candidate for a formal proof, as you just "intuited" the higher derivatives, without actually computing them. You have two possibilities:

1. Prove by induction that $f^{(n)}(0) = (-2)^n$. Do it, it's a good exercise. Then it is easy co compute the radius of convergence via e.g. the ratio test.
2. The smart way to do it: we know that $\frac{1}{1-y} = \sum_{n\ge0}y^n$ with radius of convergence $1$. Now your function is
   $$\frac{1}{1-(-2x)} = \sum_{n\ge0}(-2x)^n = \sum_{n\ge0}(-2)^nx^n$$
   with radius of convergence determined by $|-2x|<1$, that is $x<\tfrac{1}{2}$.