# Show that a power series is equivalent to a Taylor series.

Tags: proof-verification, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have the following exam Question:

> Consider the power series
>
> $$P_\infty(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{-(x-1)^k}{2k}$$
>
> 1. Examine $P_\infty(x)$ for convergence.
> 2. Determine the Taylor polynomial $T_{2}(x)$ of the function $f : \mathbb{R}_{\lt2} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = \ln{\sqrt{2 - x}}$ and
>      $x_0 = 1$
> 3. Show that $P_\infty(x)$ is the Taylor series of function $f$ at point $x_0 = 1$

Some verification for steps 1 and 2 would be nice, however as the title indicates, my main query concerns part 3.

### ----

Progress so far:

For part 1, it seems that this could be achieved via application of the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). Here I am seeking verification that my application of this is correct, and the limit can be calculated as follows:

\begin{align*}
L &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \Big| \dfrac{\frac{-(x-1)^{k+1}}{2(k+1)}}{\frac{-(x-1)^{k}}{2k}} \Big| \\
\vdots \\
&= |1 - x| \\ 
~ \\
\end{align*}

Thus, $f$ can be said to be convergent if $|x - 1| < 1$, $\hspace{0.4 cm}$ or $\hspace{0.4 cm} 0 < x < 2$.

---

For part 2, I based my calculations off the formula provided by [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/TaylorSeries.aspx) link:

$$T_2(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + \dfrac{f''(x_0)}{2!} \cdot (x-x_0)^2$$

After checking my answer on Wolfram, I concluded that 
$$T_2(x) = \dfrac{(1-x)}{2} - \dfrac{(x-1)^2}{4} $$

---

For part 3, I have tried to copy the method which was provided in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802024/determine-the-taylor-series-for-fx-x3-cdot-ln-sqrtx-around-the-poin) related question (namely, calculate furter terms of the Taylor polynomial until they can be generalized). After calculating the next term of the polynomial to be $f^3(x_0) = -\frac{1}{2}$, I concluded that $f^k(x_0) = -\frac{1}{2}$. Give this, we should have all the ingredients from the Taylor Polynomial to generalize these as the given power series, that is to say the factorial that occurs will be represented in our sum as

$\frac{1}{k!} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}$

and the part $(x-1)^k$ is already contained.

I just don't know how to present this in a mathematical way. Can someone please provide some assistance in formalizing my solution?

Answer (score 2):

For part $3$ you may consider the following approach.

$$\ln \sqrt {2-x} =(1/2) \ln (2-x) = -1/2 \int _1 ^x \frac {dt}{2-t} $$

$$ \frac {1}{2-t} = \frac {1}{1-(t-1)} = 1+(t-1)+(t-1)^2+(t-1)^3+...$$

Upon integration you get the desired infinite power series about $x_0=1$

Now you apply the uniqueness of Taylor Series to get the result.

Comment: Hi-
I think I have encountered similar approaches before, but I have a lack of understanding of power series. Maybe you can recommend some literature/elaborate on why you have suggested this solution?

Specifically, I understand that by writing the function as an integral and then integrating the series allows us to rewrite the function as a taylor series, but I don't understand when/what the limitations of rewriting a function as an integral like this are (and hence would not be able to reproduce it under exam conditions) 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may check an advanced  calculus book on infinite series and the uniqueness of Taylor series and the interval of convergence of power series. The Advanced Calculus by Patrick M. Fitzpatrick is a readable one.

Comment: thanks. I will need to inform myself before I can make any more progress on this question.